# Creating "rotate canvas" shortcuts in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to create "rotate canvas" shortcuts in QGIS?

I'm thinking about something like "Ctrl + mouse scroll up" to rotate the canvas clockwise and "Ctrl + mouse scroll down" to rotate the canvas counter clockwise.

Answer (score 6):

To rotate the canvas and assign a shortcut using Python, you could use something like the following which you could paste into the **Python Console**:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QShortcut, QKeySequence
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt

def rot_clock():
    # Rotate clockwise by 10 degrees
    rot = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().rotation()
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setRotation(rot + 10)

def rot_anticlock():
    # Rotate anti-clockwise by 10 degrees
    rot = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().rotation()
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setRotation(rot - 10)

# Assign shortcut to "Ctrl + K"
rotate_clock = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_K), iface.mainWindow())
rotate_clock.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
rotate_clock.activated.connect(rot_clock)

# Assign shortcut to "Ctrl + L"
rotate_anti = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_L), iface.mainWindow())
rotate_anti.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
rotate_anti.activated.connect(rot_anticlock)
```

If you want to assign it to the mouse wheel, you could look into the [QWheelEvent class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwheelevent.html) and try to incorporate that into the code above.

Answer (score 3):

There's similar functionality, in QGIS 2.16.3, at least.

Hover your mouse over the Rotation widget at the bottom of the screen, and roll the mouse up or down...

[image: rotate canvas widget]

- roll up or down to rotate in 5 degree steps (up=clockwise, down=counter-clockwise)
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and roll for 50 degree steps

I can't see a way to do this when hovering over the canvas, as **Settings > Configure Shortcuts** doesn't include the rotate widget as a target, and the dialog only seems to support keyboard combinations. It might be possible using Python but not looked into that.