# How can I set up a keyboard shortcut for canvas rotation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgsmapcanvas

I know that I can set canvas rotation in the bottom right corner of QGIS:

[image]

and I am aware that I can set some keyboard shortcuts via `Settings` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts...`:

[image]

However, I can't find a way to set a keyboard shortcut for **canvas rotation**.

Ideally, I would like to be able to push 1 or 2 buttons to rotate the canvas by a reasonable amount, let's say 10 degrees. Having to click slows down my workflow.

**How can I set up a keyboard shortcut for canvas rotation in QGIS?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create "rotate canvas" shortcuts in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213918/how-to-create-rotate-canvas-shortcuts-in-qgis)
You could also put the cursor in the "Rotation" box at the bottom right corner then use the mouse wheel.

Comment: Almost! It got me where I wanted to be. I submitted [an edit to this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/214088/191643), if approved, it will be a full solution to this issue, I believe.